# database synchronization - SFTP / RMAN / By codes?

Tags: database

Which method you all will recommend and why?

Comment: You should elaborate more on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention RMAN, may I assume that you are talking in particular about an Oracle database?  Or are you talking about a more generic problem?

What is the business purpose of synchronizing the databases?  That is going to strongly influence the choice of technology.  In the Oracle world, you would have DataGuard if you wanted to have a hot standby, RAC if you wanted to have a single database with load spread across multiple physical nodes of a cluster, Streams and multi-master replication if you wanted to have load spread across multiple geographically distributed databases, RMAN if you wanted to periodically clone a test database from production, etc.